# Transcripcion de una impresion en un arreglo

Tags: matrices

Tengo el siguiente codigo, y me pide modificarlo para que lo imprime que se inserte en una matriz (arreglo bidimensional), como podria hacerlo?

```
static int siguiente(int nn, int tope) {
    if (nn == tope) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return nn + 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int n = 5;
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            System.out.println(num);
            if (k != n) {
                num = siguiente(num, n);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

}

Comment: Eduardo, bienvenido a SOes. Tu pregunta en este momento es demasiado amplia. Considera agregar lo que has intentando hasta el momento, siguiendo las guias del articulo [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que ya tienes cargado tu matriz y se llama matriz1.

declara un arreglo suponiendo que es Entero (int).
Nota que **n** es el numero de posiciones. que ya debes saber. 
Esto iría en el **main**

```
int [] arreglo = new int[n]; 

for(int i = 0; i<=n; i++){
     for(int j = 0; i<=j; j++){
        int cont = 0;


arreglo [cont] = matriz1[i][j];
cont++;
```

}

}

espero te sirva de algo